# Is the concept of a basis of a module over a ring meaningful if unity is not assumed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, free-modules

Consider the following statement:

If $(x_i)_{i\in \Lambda}$ is a basis for the free $R$-module $M$, then
$$ M=\bigoplus_{i \in \Lambda}Rx_i$$
My proof:

Clearly $\sum_{i \in \Lambda}Rx_i \subseteq M$. Now, by definition of basis, M is generated by $\{x_i|i \in \Lambda\}$, meaning that $M$ is the smallest $R$-submodule of itself containing each $x_i, i \in \Lambda$. However, if $1 \in R$, then we also have $x_i\in Rx_i$ for each $i \in \Lambda$, so that $\sum_{i \in \Lambda} Rx_i$ is an $R$-submodule of $M$ containing each $x_i, i \in \Lambda.$ Thus we also have $M \subseteq \sum_{i \in \Lambda}Rx_i$, so $M=\sum_{i \in \Lambda}Rx_i$. To show that this sum is direct, suppose $y \in \sum_{i \in \Lambda}Rx_i$ is expressible in two ways (as finite sums):

$$y=\sum_{i\in \Lambda}a_ix_i=\sum_{i\in \Lambda}b_ix_i$$

Then $\sum_{i \in \Lambda}(a_i-b_i)x_i=0_M$, and by the definition $(x_i)_{i \in \Lambda}$ is a basis, so $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$. Thus: The sum is direct. $\square$

This proof depends on the fact that $1 \in R$. The question is: If $R$ is a non-unital ring, is the statement still valid? Also, is the concept of basis (and linear independence of a subset) of a module over a ring still well defined / meaningful if $R$ does not necessarily have unity?

Comment: It will depend on what you call a basis in the non unital case

Comment: Accoring to the following definitions: A basis for M is a subset $S=(x_i)_{i \in \Lambda}$ of M that (1.) Generates M and (2.) Is linearly independent.     By (1.) i mean that M is the intersection of all submodules of M containing S, and linearly independent we defined according to: If $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ is any finite list of elements of $S$, then $r_1x_1+\dots+r_nx_n=0$ for $r_1,\dots,r_n \in R$ implies $r_1=r_2=\dots=r_n=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the definition you gave in the comments, the answer is no : take the nonunital ring $2\mathbb Z$ and the module $M=\mathbb Z$, with action indiced by the restriction to $2\mathbb Z$ of the usual one.

Then $(1)$ is a basis (it generates the module because any submodule containing it contains $1$ and $2k$ for any $k$, hence $2k+1$; and it is free for obvious reasons), but of course $\mathbb Z$ isn't equal to $2\mathbb Z \cdot 1$.

In this example however, there is an isomorphism between the two. An example where that doesn't happen is $\mathbb{2Z/4Z}$ acting on $\mathbb{Z/4Z}$. Then $1$ generates it for ibvious reasons, and it is free also for obvious reasons.

However, they don't have the same cardinality so they can't even be isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for the examples   It really cleared up some of my thoughts 